# SCSS to Pure CSS translation

Tags: scss-mixins

What would be the nearest conversion of this scss to pure CSS :-

```
    .mfp-force-scrollbars {
  &.mfp-wrap {
      overflow-y: auto !important;
      overflow-x: auto !important;
  }
  .mfp-img {
    max-width: none;
  }
  .mfp-close {
   position: fixed;
  }

}
```

Comment: https://jsonformatter.org/scss-to-css

Comment: Thanks alot . I didnt know there was a converter for this .

Comment: you can use the visual code editor and install a plugin sass compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCSS code gets compiled to CSS before use. If you want to go from SCSS to CSS just compile it. There is an online compiler here: http://beautifytools.com/scss-compiler.php
but most people either use extensions in their editor (VS Code has several) or command line tools . The Sass website is here: https://sass-lang.com/ and it has documentation and installation instructions for the CLI (https://sass-lang.com/install) so you can start compiling your SCSS directly. Here is the compiled code to answer your question directly:

```
.mfp-force-scrollbars.mfp-wrap {
    overflow-y: auto !important;
    overflow-x: auto !important;
}

.mfp-force-scrollbars .mfp-img {
    max-width: none;
}

.mfp-force-scrollbars .mfp-close {
    position: fixed;
}
```

In SCSS, the `&` symbol is called the "Parent Selector" and it is used in a nested selector to repeat its direct parent. Read more here: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector

On a very minor note, if the `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` value is the same, you can just use the shorthand `overflow`. So the SCSS could just be:

```
.mfp-force-scrollbars {
    &.mfp-wrap {
      overflow: auto !important;
    }

    .mfp-img {
      max-width: none;
    }

   .mfp-close {
     position: fixed;
    }
}
```